# Grafo representado como lista ligada a lista

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, xcode, lista-encadeada, grafo

Estou tentando implementar um grafo com estrutura de lista ligada a lista puxando os dados de um arquivo txt (entrada.txt).

```
A 100 2 B 3 D 4
B 150 2 C 3 E 2
C 150 1 F 2
D 150 1 E 4
E 100 1 F 1
F 200 0
```

A ideia seja que ao ler o arquivo uma primeira vez, capturar as letras da primeira coluna e com isso criar os nós da primeira lista. Fechar o arquivo, abrir novamente e com isso começara a construir a segunda lista fazendo as conexões.
Porém apenas o primeiro caracter da primeira coluna é lido, os demais não e com isso não é criada a primeira lista, levando a estrutura a apontar para lixo de memória. 
Estou usando o Xcode.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda e atenção

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elementoarco {
int valorarco;
int usado;
struct elementoarco *proxarco;
struct elementono *padj;
} arco;

typedef struct elementono {
char dado;
int valorno;
int usado;
struct elementono *proxno;
struct elementoarco *pacessoarco;
} no;

void *Procurar (no *ginicio, char chave) {
no *n1;
n1 = ginicio;

while ((n1 != NULL) && (n1->dado != chave))
    n1 = n1->proxno;

return n1;
}

void Construir (no **ginicio) {
FILE *arq;
no *no1, *no2, *no3, *no4;
arco *arco1, *arco2;
char c;
int n, i, v;

arq = fopen ("entrada.txt", "r");
*ginicio = NULL;

int primeira = 1;

while ((c = getc (arq)) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n')
        primeira = 1;
    else
        primeira = 0;

    if (primeira == 1){
            no1 = malloc (sizeof (no));
            no1->dado = c;
            no1->valorno = 0;
            no1->usado = 0;
            no1->pacessoarco = NULL;
            no1->proxno = NULL;

            if (*ginicio == NULL)
                *ginicio = no1;

            else
                no2->proxno = no1;

            no2 = no1;
    }
}
/*
fclose(arq);
arq = fopen ("entrada.txt", "r");
*/
while ((c = getc (arq)) != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n') {
        no3 = Procurar (*ginicio, c);

        printf("%c", no3->dado);

        fscanf (arq, "%d ", &n);

        no3->valorno = n;

        fscanf (arq, "%d ", &n);

        for (i = 1; i != n + 1; i++) {
            c = getc (arq);

            arco1 = malloc (sizeof (arco));

            fscanf (arq, "%d ", &v);

            arco1->valorarco = v;
            arco1->usado = 0;

            no4 = Procurar(*ginicio, c);
            arco1->padj = no4;

            arco1->proxarco = NULL;

            if (no3->pacessoarco == NULL)
                no3->pacessoarco = arco1;
            else
                arco2->proxarco = arco1;

            arco2 = arco1;
        }
    }
}

fclose (arq);
return;
}


int main() {
no *ginicio;

Construir (&ginicio);

no *teste;
arco *arcoteste;

teste = ginicio;

while (teste != NULL) {
    printf("%c", teste->dado);
    printf("\t%i", teste->valorno);
    printf("\t%i", teste->usado);

    arcoteste = teste->pacessoarco;

    printf("\n");

    while (arcoteste != NULL) {
        printf(" Arco: %c", arcoteste->padj->dado);
        printf(" Valor do Arco: %d", arcoteste->valorarco);
        printf("\n");
        arcoteste = arcoteste->proxarco;
    }

    printf("\n");
    teste = teste->proxno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A parte do segundo fclose está comentada pois com ela não compila.